# Is there a function to concatenate two char16_t

Tags: c++, function, concatenation, wchar-t, char16-t

There is the function `wcsncat_s()` for concatenating two `wchar_t*`:

```
errno_t wcsncat_s( wchar_t *restrict dest, rsize_t destsz, const wchar_t *restrict src, rsize_t count );
```

**Is there an equivalent function for concatenating two `char16_t`?**

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: No, but you can write one yourself.

Comment: Concatenate two individual `char16_t` characters, or two `char16_t*` strings? Why are you not using `std::u16string`? Then you can use its `operator+`

Comment: Why tag with `C++` if you are looking for `C` function? As Remy point out in C++ just use `std::u16string`.

Answer (score 2):

Not really.

On Windows, though, `wchar_t` is functionally identical to `char16_t`, so you could just cast your `char16_t*` to a `wchar_t*`.

Otherwise you can do it simply enough by writing yourself a function for it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [std::u16string](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/u16string/) if you want something portable.

```
std::u16string str1(u16"The quick brown fox ");
std::u16string str2(u16"Jumped over the lazy dog");

std::u16string str3 = str1+str2;  // concatenate

const char16_t* psz = str3.c_str();
```

The validity of `psz` lasts as long as `str3` doesn't go out of out scope.

But the more portable and flexible solution is to just use wchar_t everywhere (which is 32-bit on Mac).  Unless you are explicitly using 16-bit char strings (perhaps for a specific UTf16 processing routine), it's easier to just keep your code in the wide char (`wchar_t`) space.  Plays nicer with native APIs and libraries on Mac and Windows.